# Utilizar el botón back de Android para volver a la página anterior estando en un Fragment

Tags: java, android

Quiero utilizar el botón back de Android para volver a la página anterior estando en un Fragment. Antes se cerraba la aplicación directamente, pero el código que tengo ahora me parece que tiene que funcionar, pero le falta algo. Este código es de otro post que he encontrado aquí, pero no me vuelve a la página en que estaba yo antes.

Supongo que lo debería hacer en el **MainActivity.java**, pero cuando meto allí el **getActivity().onBackPressed();** me sale que no FragmentManager ya está ejecutando una transacción...

Lo he marcado con un asterisco abajo.

**Fragment**

```
public class PostDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private String postid;
    private PostAdapter postAdapter;
    private List<Post> postList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post_detail, container, false);

      ((DrawerLocker) getActivity()).setDrawerLocked(true);

        postList = new ArrayList<>();
        postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), postList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);

        readPosts();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        ((DrawerLocker) getActivity()).setDrawerLocked(false);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

**  @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();
        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                return event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DrawerLocker, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ImageView image_profile;
    TextView fullname;

    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    String profileid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        //Dealing with the header
        View headerLayout = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        image_profile = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        fullname = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.fullname_header);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        profileid = prefs.getString("profileid", "none");

        //Called method userInfo() from EditProfile.java here so that header picture changes.
        userInfo();

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);

        Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (intent != null) {
            String publisher = intent.getString("publisherid");

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("profileid", publisher);
            editor.apply();

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new ProfileFragment()).commit();
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new HomeFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        int id = menuItem.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_edit_profile:
                Intent editProfile = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(editProfile);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                Intent settings = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(settings);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                Intent logout = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class)
                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.nav_edit_profile) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_search:
                            selectedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_notifications:
                            selectedFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_profile:
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putString("profileid", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                            editor.apply();
                            selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_save:
                            selectedFragment = new SaveFragment();
                            break;
                    }

                    if (selectedFragment != null) {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                selectedFragment).commit();
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            };

    public void setDrawerLocked(boolean enabled) {
        if (enabled) {
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        } else {
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        }

    }

    private void userInfo() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (getApplicationContext() == null) {
                    return;
                }

                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if (user != null) {
                    fullname.setText(user.getFullname());
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageurl()).into(image_profile);
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para regresar puedes simplemente llamar el mètodo `onBackPressed()` de la `Activity` que contiene el `Fragment`:

```
getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

esto se realiza para cerrar la Activity y regresar a una anterio.

---

Actualizaciòn:

El usuario desea cambiar de Fragment de `PostDetailFragment` a `HomeFragment`, entonces lo que se realiza en este caso es una Transacciòn de Fragmentos:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: He añadido el código arriba de MainActivity. Supongo que tiene que ir allí, pero cuando he escrito el getActivity().onBackPressed(); en el PostDetailFragment me ga dado un crash. Lo pongo directamente en el MainActivity o cómo hago?

Comment: El error me sale en la linea ```super.onBackPressed();```

Comment: Tienes un Fragment que esta cargado en una Activity, quieres salir de este fragment y regresar a la Activity? Si es asi que cargarìa la Activity?

Comment: Bueno, estoy en HomeFragment y luego le doy a un post y me lleva a PostDetailFragment. Quiero darle al botón de Android para que me vuelva al HomeFragment. Y HomeFragment está en MainActivity supongo el código que he subido ya.

Comment: Ya que lo pienso en todos los Fragments que tengo si le doy al botón de volver de Android se me cierra la aplicación, pero no en plan un crash. Se cierra y ya está...

Comment: Ah, en este caso se realiza una transaccion de Fragments debes cambiar a HomeFragment: getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit(); actualice la respuesta.

Comment: Vale, y esto lo tengo que añadir a PostDetailFragment? Me sale el getSupportFragmentManager(). en rojo. En MainActivity ya tengo ese código... Mira a ver si está bien o no, pero en MainActivity ya tengo algo parecido

Comment: Desde un Fragment recuerda usar getActivity() de esta forma : getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()...........

Comment: Podemos hablar en el chat un momento... No me sale como debería [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105340/discussion-between-johnnnn-and-jorgesys).

Comment: Bueno, no funciona como yo quiero, pues ahora le doy a un post y me lleva a HomeFragment. Yo necesito poder manejar con los botones (back) de Android. Para volver a la página anterior en que estaba